# Why this html button sent get request?

Tags: java, spring, post, get, thymeleaf

this code sent get request, why?

```
<form th:action="@{/books/edit/rename}" th:object="${book}" th:method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" th:value="*{id}" value="1"/>
        <input type="text" id="bookName" name="bookName" th:value="*{bookName}" value="nameExample"/>
        <button type="submit">Rename for model</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have some js which process that form?

Comment: Use View Source in your browser and include the source that the browser sees.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the *th:* in the method declaration, to be as the following:

```
<form th:action="@{/books/edit/rename}" th:object="${book}" method="POST">
…
```

Because it is not reading the code and the default is GET, check this for more details https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: did not help( Request URL: http://localhost:8080/books/edit.html?id=1&bookName=Triller
Request Method: GET

Comment: @Alexandr from the posted link it seems as if the target is something different as well, as the request does not point to `books/edit/rename` but `books/edit.html`

So either what you are seeing as an already processed request, in which you simply failed to remove the request data, or the form that is actually used is different from the one you posted.